# Scene Builder: How to hide borders on panels, etc

Tags: java, javafx, border, hide, scenebuilder

I'm just starting with Scene Builder and java. I've laid out my main GUI but when I preview it, it has wide borders for all my h/v boxes, anchor panels, etc. How do I hide the borders when I actually run (preview) my UI? Is there a way in scene builder (preferred) or will I have to code this instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Default border on layouts

There is NO `default-border` on `layouts` which can be visible. In case, you need to remove border from layouts you can set `css` code using `setStyle()` method,

```
yourPane.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 0px");
```

You can also use [external css document](//istackoverflow.com/questions/22066799/how-to-use-external-css-file-to-style-a-javafx-application) for styling components.

### Wide border on preview

Actually, the fxml preview means that `showing your design in a window`. So you might get confused with `window frame border` as shown in the below preview,

[image: window frame with border]

But you can make `borderles- window` by styling your stage using `initStyle()`,

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

You can also use `TRANSPARENT` style as well but you have to [manage your title bar for customized-window](//stackoverflow.com/questions/9861178/javafx-primarystage-remove-windows-borders).

[image: customized undecorated window]
<sub>(source: [makery.ch](https://code.makery.ch/assets/blog/12-10-30-javafx-2-dialogs/javafx-custom-dialog.png))</sub>